# Replace kinect avateering model

Tags: kinect, 3dsmax

I am trying to change dude model in kinect avateering I have tryied so many ways no one goes wright except when I replaced TGA files
I opened dude.fbx using 3D max and try just to import and re export it it goes wrong and i had errors in building
I have tried to replace the whoke dude.fbx file with a nother fbx human model file and always get the same error
"no input skeleton found
to be more specific i am doing a virtual dressing room using 3d models to make it more stable than using video processing so i need to create a 3d human modeling using programmimng language so i just used dude model
please any help in that

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing a Virtual dressing room project and i too struggled with that damn dude. There is a tutorial which is about the same topic you are trying.

http://mopred.blogspot.com/2012/11/changing-avateering-avatar-in-kinect.html

but i think the best way to create your own models and turn, rotate and translating them is then easy. animating a boned model would be so hard.